# SetTimeout in Angular 5 Service

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to have a property `currentAndLastVehicles` in my service, which will be automatically change every second.

So far:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SharedDataService {

  constructor() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("hello");
      this.currentAndLastVehicles = [(Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000000 - 9999999)) + 9999999).toString(),...this.currentAndLastVehicles];
    }, 1000);
  }

  public currentAndLastVehicles : string[] = [];
}
```

Problems:

- setTimeout will only be executed once (most likely because `setTimeout` is located in the constructor)
- `setTimeout` outside of the constructor leads multiple errors

What can I do to achieve the desired behaviour?

Comment: use `setInterval`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `setInterval`.

Until you call clearInterval it will be executed. you can call the `clearInterval` by creating a method in the service and execute `ngOnDestroy` of AppComponent

In your constructor you should use the variable

```
constructor(){
     this.clearIntervalInstance = this.myFunction();
}
```

You should have the function in your service as

```
myFunction() {
   setInterval(()=>{
      this.currentAndLastVehicles = [(Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000000 - 9999999)) + 9999999).toString(),...this.currentAndLastVehicles];
},10000)
```

In the app component

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.service.clearIntervalMethod()
}
```

In your service

```
clearIntervalMethod(){
  clearInterval(this.clearIntervalInstance);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by In the app component ? Where exactly?

Comment: You're setInterval will be running endlessly. So to clear it I have the logic of ngOnDestroy

Comment: But why not directly in the service?
e.g.
`export class SharedDataService implements OnDestroy {...ngOnDestroy(...`

Comment: I guess services cannot have life cycle hooks.

Answer (score 3):

The `setTimeout` will only run once, if you want every second you must use the `setInterval` function.

Comment: this was my comment. in the post

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to reload your data every second you can use a reactive approach like so.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/interval';

@Injectable()
export class SharedDataService {
  poll$: Observable<any>;

  constructor() {
    this.poll$.interval(1000).subscribe(() => {
      return this.currentAndLastVehicles = [(Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000000 - 9999999)) + 9999999).toString(),...this.currentAndLastVehicles];
    }
  }

  public currentAndLastVehicles : string[] = [];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To ran a function `EVERY` X seconds till it is cancelled,, use `setInterval`

```
setInterval(() => {
      console.log("hello");
      this.currentAndLastVehicles = [(Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000000 - 9999999)) + 9999999).toString(),...this.currentAndLastVehicles];
    }, 1000);
 }
```

Please note that you might want to store the value returned by `setInterval` so that you can cancel it if need be.